# biblatex declare with multiple bibliographies

Tags: biblatex

I have three bibliographies, which utilize categories and keywords to separate all the entries

```
\printbibliography[title={Publications related to theses},category=cited,heading=subbibliography,keyword=ownpub]

\printbibliography[title={Publications unrelated to theses},category=notcited,heading=subbibliography,keyword=ownpub]

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,resetnumbers=true,notcategory=cited,notcategory=notcited,notkeyword=ownpub]
```

I want the first two to have different styles than the last one. I found the commands on the internet to modify the behaviour of the first two to work in the way I want it (bold author name and different style of numbering).

the numbering:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{{#1\adddot}}
```

the name:

```
\newcommand{\makeauthorbold}[1]{%
\DeclareNameFormat{author}{%
  \edef\tempname{{Ferdinandy}}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{1}
    {\ifnumequal{\value{liststop}}{1}
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal\tempname{##1}{\textbf{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal\tempname{##1}{\textbf{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}{##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}}
    {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal\tempname{##1}{\textbf{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4}}
      {\expandafter\ifstrequal\tempname{##1}{\textbf{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}{\addcomma\addspace ##1\addcomma\addspace ##4\addcomma\isdot}}%
    }%
}%
}
```

Looking at the `biblatex` manual, I see that it is possible to apply a `\DeclareFieldFormat` based on the keywords, but it implies to me, that if I touch a field with this, I will have to supply the default behaviour myself (i.e. it is not possible to override default behaviour if my condition is true, I will have to supply both the true and the false condition).

> `\ifkeyword {〈keyword〉}{〈true〉}{〈false〉}` Executes `〈true〉`
>   if the `〈keyword〉` is found in the keywords field of the entry
>   currently being processed, and `〈false〉` otherwise.

Is this true, or is there a way to override default behaviour for specific `\printbibliography` instances? The latter would be much more straightforward, then having to use several nested ifs (and very possible listing the default behaviour more than once). If true, where can I find the definitions of the default behaviours?

Comment: The defaults can be found in `biblatex.def`/`standard.bbx` (find them with `kpsewhich`). Can you maybe describe in more detail what you want/need and give a proper [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)? Otherwise your question is really hard to answer safe for the reference to the defaults.

Comment: Maybe it is enough to keep some of the redefinitions local for your purpose. Try to redefine the commands locally in a group before the respective `\printbibliography`s.

Comment: What do you mean by locally in a group?

Comment: You can do `{\DeclareNameFormat{author}{foo}\printbibliography}` - note the curly braces (presumably, at least, I couldn't test for lack of an MWE) to change the author format for only the following `\printbibliography`.

Comment: Wow, it works, good thought! Much more elegant than the `savefieldformat`, `restorefieldformat` solution. If you post it as an answer I'll accept that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep the redefinitions local with grouping

```
{\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}
 \printbibliography[category=cited, keyword=ownpub]
 \printbibliography[category=notcited, keyword=ownpub]}

\printbibliography[resetnumbers=true, notcategory=cited, notcategory=notcited, notkeyword=ownpub]
```

or

```
\begingroup
  \DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{#1\adddot}
  \printbibliography[category=cited, keyword=ownpub]
  \printbibliography[category=notcited, keyword=ownpub]
\endgroup

\printbibliography[resetnumbers=true, notcategory=cited, notcategory=notcited, notkeyword=ownpub]
```

This might be more efficient than `\seveformat`/`\restoreformat` in some situations, but it might also be less elegant in some contexts.

Answer (score 1):

I actually found a solution to this using `savefieldformat` and `restorefieldformat`. Doesn't seem very elegant though.

```
\savefieldformat{labelnumberwidth} %save current settings
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{{#1\adddot}} %modify for following printbibliographies

\printbibliography[title={Publications related to theses},category=cited,heading=subbibliography,keyword=ownpub]
\printbibliography[title={Publications unrelated to theses},category=notcited,heading=subbibliography,keyword=ownpub]

\restorefieldformat{labelnumberwidth} %restore what we saved

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,resetnumbers=true,notcategory=cited,notcategory=notcited,notkeyword=ownpub]
```